# Windows 2008 R2:Files in Windows Search Results are not able to be deleted

Tags: windows-search

As title says, I am searching .eml files in some dir with keywords, the .eml files'content are indexed. Listing the results, I click mouse right button, no delete choice. How can I delete files from windows search result ? ( I tried it on my laptop running Windows 7 Ultimate, it works fine)

Anyone could tell the answer ?